# Install Ubuntu Desktop Variable From CD

Tags: xubuntu, lubuntu, desktop-environments

How To Install Ubuntu Desktop Variations (such as lubuntu-xubuntu) from installation cd?

Comment: no. look. i have xubuntu installed here and i have most of ubuntu variant cds downloaded, i want to enter apt-get install for ex. lubuntu-desktop so it will install lubuntu beside xubuntu. but this command will download lubuntu. i dont want to download it. i want to install from cd. also please dont vote down my questions.

Answer (score 2):

Each variant has it's own CD image that you would need to download and then burn. It's much better to make a USB installer and boot to that if possible. ;)

Here's some to get you started:

- http://lubuntu.net/
- http://www.kubuntu.org/getkubuntu
- http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/ubuntu-kylin
- http://ubuntugnome.org/download/
- http://www.linuxmint.com/index.php
- http://xubuntu.org/

Comment: linuxmint is not an official Ubuntu variant.